# Connecting to Hotmail through telnet

Tags: proxy, telnet

My ISP has port 25 blocked. I tried using Hotstop Shield to get around it, but the server identifies the proxy as spam'er. Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use a proxy. You can connect to Hotmail's mail server using the well-known port 587 ([e-mail message submission](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4409.txt)).

Your ISP shouldn't block port 587, since it's intended specifically to submit a mail to a mail submission agent. Meanwhile, connections to port 25 could be used to send spam directly from your computer.

Comment: Also blocked. Just tried to connect.

Comment: I went to a website which checks for open ports and it seems to be unreachable.

Comment: That's odd, since there's no good reason to block connections to port 587. Which website?

Comment: http://www.canyouseeme.org

Comment: That site checks for open machines on *your* machine. You have to connect to Hotmail's mail server using and *outgoing* connection on *their* port 587. That's entirely different. Just try `telnet smtp.live.com 587`.